# How to properly use user registration in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, registration

I am new to ServiceStack and I am having some problems truly understanding the user registration stuff. Our goal is to:

1. Allow a user to create a new account
2. Verify if a user name and/or email is already in use
3. Automatically log the user in after registering
4. Return JWT token with response

I am currently using the RegisterService located [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/a5ab5306fa69457e58be4bb835b04844a6226ac2/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs#L74) for all of our user registration logic.

The problem seems to be that after a user registers any other user can register with the same user name and/or email and all it does is updates the previous users data. I have noticed that when I restart the API that the line:

RegistrationValidator?.ValidateAndThrow(request, registerNewUser ? ApplyTo.Post : ApplyTo.Put);

will throw an error if a user name or email already exists. However, as I just explained once a new user registers, another user right after them can use the exact same info and all it does is updates the user before it. This is not the desired result.

Why does the validation seem to work if I restart the API, but not while it is running?

As I step through the code I have noticed that this.GetSession() seems to return a new session with basically everything set to null when the API is first started, but once a user logs in or registers GetSessions() returns the most recent user session.

I apologize in advance if I come off like I know nothing, like I said I am very new to ServiceStack and I have pretty much spent the past couple of days at work trying to figure this out. I have scoured many forums including ServicStacks customer forums and even here. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT" Post effort and CODE in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

> The problem seems to be that after a user registers any other user can register with the same user name and/or email and all it does is updates the previous users data.

Only the current user can update their User Registration Info after they're registered. You can return to being an Unauthenticated the user out by calling `/auth/logout` to clear their session or if using a Service Client:

```
client.Post(new Authenticate { provider = "logout" });
```

> Why does the validation seem to work if I restart the API, but not
>   while it is running?

Because the User is authenticated and you're using the default In Memory Cache Client where [Sessions are saved to](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) and restarting the App Domain clears all User Sessions so all previously authenticated are now unauthenticated.

There's a few different options to achieve your desired outcome:

#### Register then Authenticate the user

1. Use the Register Service to create a new Account. The Registration Service will throw if the Username or Email is in use.
2. On successful registration, call the `Authenticate` Service (`/auth/credentials`) to authenticate the user using the new credentials. If the JWT AuthProvider is registered and it's called using `https` or the JWT Auth Provider is configured with `RequireSecureConnection=false` it will return the JWT Token and Refresh Token.

If you [Authenticate with UseTokenCookie=true](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#request-jwt-cookie-is-set-on-authentication) then the Authenticated UserSession is converted into a JWT Token and returned in the `ss-tok` Cookie.

#### Register the user with AutoLogin then convert Session to Token

Auto login with the Register Service, calling the `Register` Service with `AutoLogin=true` will authenticate the User after registering them in the same request, but the `RegisterResponse` DTO that the Register Service returns doesn't contain the JWT Token, instead you can [call /session-to-token](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#ajax-clients) to convert the current authenticated User Session into a JWT Token which is returned in the `ss-tok` Cookie which is sent with subsequent requests to make authenticated requests.

#### Register the user with AutoLogin with latest version

I've just added support for returning the JWT Token and Refresh Token in `AutoLogin` Register Requests in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/7b4a1fd52ce434c54e52bdb4dbaf7bac1af5f1d0) so you can just register the User with:

```
var response = client.Post(new Register {
    //...
    AutoLogin = true
});
```

And you'll be able to access the JWT tokens in:

```
response.BearerToken   //JWT Token
response.RefreshToken  //JWT RefreshToken
```

This change is available from v4.5.15 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Hi @mythz, thank you for the quick response! 

My colleague and I just did a test by registering a user from two different machines with the same info. I registered as expected but once he tried to register it just updated the info since the session still exists. Logging out the user is not an acceptable route for us. We could be having thousands of user registering at once in which they could have conflicting user names.

So if one user registers in California with user name "bob" and a user registers in Ohio with the same user name than the Ohio user would overwrite the California user.

Comment: @mlangwell that doesn't sound right, can you put together a small stand-alone App I can run locally to see the issue.

Comment: I have our API down to being very basic, and I believe you should be able to run it locally. How would you like for me to send it to you?

Comment: @mlangwell easiest way is to put it on GitHub and send me the link

Comment: [Here it is](https://github.com/mlangwell/SS_UserRegistration/tree/master/WebApplication1)

Please let me know if there is anything else you need!

Comment: @mlangwell not sure what I'm meant to do with this, it's using your own custom RegistrationFeature + Registration Service and ServiceStack isn't even configured in Web.config so this has never run? Please provide a stand-alone repro I can run locally that contains the exact steps in order to repro the issue you're referring to.

Comment: @mlangwell I've re-tested this again locally and the only way I've able to update the user is if I'm authenticated which also doesn't allow updating the user name or Email to an existing user. I've added a `RegistrationFeature.DisableUpdates` flag where you can disable the existing user from updating their info. This change is available from v4.5.15 that's [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget). I've created a PR with your project to [highlight a number of irregularities](https://github.com/mlangwell/SS_UserRegistration/pull/1/commits/c7d6aef230ccfd38017708feebf0cf3599394f51)

Comment: Thank you for taking a look and adding some changes. I apologize about it being incomplete. Our project was set up by someone else and I had to completely strip out all of our company stuff due to security reasons within the company. That is why it seems so incomplete. I will make sure my team lead takes a look at this and see what we can do to include your changes. Thanks again